# which part of the code is giving connection refused error?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, connection

I am trying to understand VAE by running the code at: https://github.com/kuc2477/pytorch-vae

I changed the dataset folder and copy pasted everything to jupyter notebook (I get the same error without jupyter notebook as well). I suspect error must be coming somewhere from train.py so I modified the code there (where iterations are happening as):

tot_itrs = 0
for epoch in range(epoch_start, epochs+1):

```
#data_loader = utils.get_data_loader(dataset, batch_size, cuda=cuda)
data_loader = get_data_loader(dataset, batch_size, cuda=cuda)
data_stream = tqdm(enumerate(data_loader, 1))

for batch_index, (x, _) in data_stream:
    print(tot_itrs, end=' ')
    tot_itrs += 1
    # where are we?
    iteration = (epoch-1)*(len(dataset)//batch_size) + batch_index

    # prepare data on gpu if needed
    x = Variable(x).cuda() if cuda else Variable(x)

    # flush gradients and run the model forward
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    (mean, logvar), x_reconstructed = model(x)
    reconstruction_loss = model.reconstruction_loss(x_reconstructed, x)
    kl_divergence_loss = model.kl_divergence_loss(mean, logvar)
    total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_divergence_loss

    # backprop gradients from the loss
    total_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    # update progress
    data_stream.set_description((
        'epoch: {epoch} | '
        'iteration: {iteration} | '
        'progress: [{trained}/{total}] ({progress:.0f}%) | '
        'loss => '
        'total: {total_loss:.4f} / '
        're: {reconstruction_loss:.3f} / '
        'kl: {kl_divergence_loss:.3f}'
    ).format(
        epoch=epoch,
        iteration=iteration,
        trained=batch_index * len(x),
        total=len(data_loader.dataset),
        progress=(100. * batch_index / len(data_loader)),
        total_loss=total_loss.data.item(),
        reconstruction_loss=reconstruction_loss.data.item(),
        kl_divergence_loss=kl_divergence_loss.data.item(),
    ))
    if iteration % loss_log_interval == 0:
        print("iteration % loss_log_interval == 0:")
        losses = [
            reconstruction_loss.data.item(),
            kl_divergence_loss.data.item(),
            total_loss.data.item(),
        ]
        names = ['reconstruction', 'kl divergence', 'total']
        #visual.visualize_scalars(
        visualize_scalars(
            losses, names, 'loss',
            iteration, env=model.name)

    if iteration % image_log_interval == 0:
        print("iteration % image_log_interval == 0:")
        images = model.sample(sample_size)
        #visual.visualize_images(
        visualize_images(
            images, 'generated samples',
            env=model.name
        )

# notify that we've reached to a new checkpoint.
print()
print()
print('#############')
print('# checkpoint!')
print('#############')
print()

# save the checkpoint.
#utils.save_checkpoint(model, checkpoint_dir, epoch)
save_checkpoint(model, checkpoint_dir, epoch)
print()
```

When I run this, I gt following error/ouput

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/_reduction.py:44: UserWarning: size_average and reduce args will be deprecated, please use reduction='sum' instead.
  warnings.warn(warning.format(ret))
epoch: 1 | iteration: 23 | progress: [1472/60000] (2%) | loss => total: 904.5577 / re: 900.121 / kl: 4.437: : 23it [00:00, 109.19it/s]
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
epoch: 1 | iteration: 46 | progress: [2944/60000] (5%) | loss => total: 867.7250 / re: 858.849 / kl: 8.876: : 35it [00:00, 111.48it/s]
23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
epoch: 1 | iteration: 69 | progress: [4416/60000] (7%) | loss => total: 822.9196 / re: 804.030 / kl: 18.889: : 59it [00:00, 113.42it/s]
 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
epoch: 1 | iteration: 92 | progress: [5888/60000] (10%) | loss => total: 770.0244 / re: 742.728 / kl: 27.296: : 83it [00:00, 113.52it/s]
 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 
epoch: 1 | iteration: 100 | progress: [6400/60000] (11%) | loss => total: 754.4070 / re: 724.972 / kl: 29.435: : 95it [00:00, 113.77it/s]Setting up a new session...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 182, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4941e8f048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8097): Max retries exceeded with url: /env/VAE-128k-mnist-1x32x32 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4941e8f048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/visdom/__init__.py", line 711, in _send
    data=json.dumps(msg),
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/visdom/__init__.py", line 677, in _handle_post
    r = self.session.post(url, data=data)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 590, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8097): Max retries exceeded with url: /env/VAE-128k-mnist-1x32x32 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4941e8f048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
[Errno 111] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 182, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4941be06a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8097): Max retries exceeded with url: /events (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4941be06a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/visdom/__init__.py", line 711, in _send
    data=json.dumps(msg),
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/visdom/__init__.py", line 677, in _handle_post
    r = self.session.post(url, data=data)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 590, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aknirala/anaconda3/envs/gan_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8097): Max retries exceeded with url: /events (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4941be06a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
epoch: 1 | iteration: 103 | progress: [6592/60000] (11%) | loss => total: 756.0789 / re: 727.468 / kl: 28.611: : 95it [00:01, 113.77it/s]
92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 iteration % loss_log_interval == 0:
Exception in user code:
------------------------------------------------------------
Exception in user code:
------------------------------------------------------------
100 101 102 103 
epoch: 1 | iteration: 127 | progress: [8128/60000] (14%) | loss => total: 711.3364 / re: 680.982 / kl: 30.354: : 119it [00:01, 94.96it/s]
104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126
```

From where is this exception being thrown (not the warning but the exception which ultimately says:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8097): Max retries exceeded with url: /events (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4941be06a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

) and how can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [Visdom](https://github.com/fossasia/visdom). You could run the Visdom server in the background to make this error go away by running `python -m visdom.server`.

This error happens with many projects. For e.g., look [here](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/issues/24).